# Can ads can be removed AFTER they appear?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, dom-manipulation

I have written some Ad-removal scripts which I deploy locally with Greasemonkey on FF. They should work by DOM Manipuation. 
Unfortunately the Ads are loaded afterwards my monkeyscript runs. Can I change the runtime order, so Ads can be removed AFTER they appear?

On Tampermonkey (on Chrome), there are configurations about runtime (see below). I don't understand them. Tried them all, nothing works.

[image: Runtime options]
<sup>(Click for larger view.)</sup>

Comment: Oh come on. Spiegel Onlines ads are not intrusive or annoying at all, and they publish big parts of the spiegel for free so i think it would be fair to let the ads on. But still: If you want to get help on how a certain programs work, please contact its author and read through the FAQs...

Comment: inject a regular external script with xxxmonkey, which i actually find simpler and easier to maintain.

Comment: None of those options matter for ajax-driven content, which is what you are apparently dealing with.  See the linked answer.